# Why my tkinter code takes too long to run

Tags: python, tkinter

I have created a gui with tkinter which contains many gifs and images.
When I run it, it takes too long to start. I have not used any multitasking, and all of my code is in only one file, because I am not able to seperate it properly.

I have tried threading module but I guess it is not having any effect.i am beginner so I don't know much.

```
error = "No Error"
import tkinter as tk
from PIL import Image
import threading
    
root = tk.Tk()
file="C:\\Users\\mishr\\.vscode\\Practice\\Projects\\F.R.I.D.A.Y\\3.gif"
root.geometry("2020x1280")
root.title("F.R.I.D.A.Y")
root.state('zoomed')
root.minsize(2020,1280)

root.configure(highlightthickness=2,highlightbackground="black")
bg = True
Error = False
stop = False
# root.overrideredirect(3) #Remove border

info = Image.open(file)
frames = info.n_frames 
im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]
count = 0
anim = None
def animation(count):
    global anim
    im2 = im[count]
    gif_label.configure(image=im2)
    count += 1
    if count == frames:
        count = 0
    anim = root.after(50,lambda :animation(count))

def stop_animation():
    root.after_cancel(anim)

gif_label = tk.Label(root,image="",bg="black")
gif_label.place(x=1100,y=-100)
root.config(bg="black")

a = threading.Thread(target=animation(count))
a.start()

from tkinter import*

if bg:
    from PIL import Image
    from PIL import ImageTk
    Image=Image.open("C:\\Users\\mishr\\.vscode\\Practice\\Projects\\F.R.I.D.A.Y\\panel.png")

    # intrect menu
    size=(1170,370)
    Image=Image.resize(size)
    image1=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image)
    imglabel1=Label(root,image=image1,borderwidth=0)
    imglabel1.pack(anchor=SW,pady=1)

    # loading menu
    size3=(380,400)
    Image2=Image.resize(size3)
    image3=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image2)
    imglabel3=Label(root,image=image3,borderwidth=0,pady=10)
    imglabel3.pack(side="left")


    # Error menu
    size2=(1160,400)
    Image1=Image.resize(size2)
    image2=ImageTk.PhotoImage(Image1)
    imglabel2=Label(root,image=image2,borderwidth=0,pady=10)
    imglabel2.pack(side="left")

def time():
    import tkinter as tk
    frame2=tk.Frame(root)
    frame2.place(x=1360,y=715)

    from datetime import date
    today = date.today()
    from pytz import timezone 
    from datetime import datetime

    time=tk.Label(frame2,bg="Black",fg="White",font=("",30))
    time.pack()
    def timeupdate():    
        ind_time = datetime.now(timezone("Asia/Kolkata")).strftime('%H:%M:%S')
        time.config(text=str(ind_time).split(".")[0])
        frame2.after(100,timeupdate)

    timeupdate()


error_label = Label(imglabel2,text=error,fg="cyan",bg="Black",font=("",11,"bold"),anchor="w")
error_label.place(x=20,y=50,anchor="w")

try:
    t = threading.Thread(target=time)
    t.start()
except :
    error = "Some error has occured while importing functions .\n Now it is possible for some animations or clock to stop ,\n try contacting developer to resolve the problem.\n Developer contact --- Virat32785@gmail.com "

error_label.configure(text=error)
root.update()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: How long is "too long"? You could run it in a debugger or add `print`s to see what takes how long.

Comment: Your use of threading is invalid - `target=animation(count)` calls the function *right now*, in the main thread, and uses its return value (which is None) as the target of the thread.  Which is probably for the best, since it's not safe to interact with Tkinter from a thread anyway.  Threading would only be useful here to run a non-GUI process while allowing the GUI to remain responsive.

Answer (score 0):

Suggest to use [`Pillow.ImageSequence`](https://pillow.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/ImageSequence.html) module to load the GIF image:

```py
...
from PIL import Image, ImageTk, ImageSequence
...
image = Image.open(file)
frames = image.n_frames
#im = [tk.PhotoImage(file=file,format=f"gif -index {i}") for i in range(frames)]
im = [ImageTk.PhotoImage(frame) for frame in ImageSequence.Iterator(image)]
...
```